# Error adding line in mysql with correct syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked at several answers already but none are solving my problem.

I want to insert several lines into my table and am using the following code:

INSERT INTO `teams` (id,`'name'`,`'password'`) VALUES(2,`'Aston Villa'`,`'aston villa'`);

column types are: int,varchar,varchar

But I keep getting the following error:

> "#1054 - Unknown column '2' in 'field list'"

*Also if I want to hash the password inline would I believe I would do it like this but I am still receiving the same error*

```
INSERT INTO `teams`(ID, `name`, `password`) VALUES (`2`,`Aston Villa`,SHA256(`".$astonvilla."`));
```

Comment: What are the data types of your columns?

Comment: Why TEXT, do you mean VARCHAR ?

Comment: using SHOW COLUMNS FROM `teams` thats what i get. Ill change them to varchar now

Comment: I have changed the formats to now be int, varchar, varchar but error still persists

Comment: You are using back quotes around the literal value 2, mysql uses back quotes to delimit schema object names. You have also used them for the other values but ``2`` was the first to fail. Use `'single quotes'`.

Comment: Thanks this worked, this is the first time i've had to use single quotes. My understanding of sql is increasing day by day

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are wrapping your Values properly:

```
$insert = printf("INSERT INTO teams(`ID`, `name`, `password`) VALUES (2,'Aston Villa',SHA256('%s'));", $astonvilla);
```

Comment: Would this prevent '2' from causing the same error?

Comment: Since 2 is an integer and I making the jump that ID is an INT data type, the 2 value without single quotes wrapping it, will be valid. Column '2' in 'field list' means that it could not find a value for ``name``.

Comment: Oh, I thought the unknown column error always included the attempted column name rather than the column number. I guess I need to reread.

Comment: I recently had a similar issue and it gave the Index and not the name when using MySQLi. The resulting Error message should be the same regardless of module since it's coming from MySQL. So maybe a config preference changed?